# Oracle SQL; simple query yielding "not a group by statement"

Tags: sql, oracle

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
This simple query appears to be a valid SQL group by statement.  What am I missing?  Each grouping field is included in the group by?

EDIT:
I was able to get the query to run by simply casting the SUM to decimal.  Can anyone explain the below?

Broken query:

```
/* ERROR: not a group by expression */
select account, to_char(trans_date, 'mm-yyyy') mnth_yr,
       sum(total_duration)/60 as mou   
from chuck.cdr_data_summary@chuckdb
where rate_band_type = 'ALC1' and account = '0204927766' and description_text like '%Inbound%'
      and trans_date >= '01-jan-2019' and trans_date < '01-jan-2020'
group by account, to_char(trans_date, 'mm-yyyy')
order by account;
```

Working query:

```
/* no error;  only change was the cast(... as decimal..)*/
select account, to_char(trans_date, 'mm-yyyy') mnth_yr,
       cast(sum(total_duration)/60 as decimal(18,2)) as mou   
from chuck.cdr_data_summary@chuckdb
where rate_band_type = 'ALC1' and account = '0204927766' and description_text like '%Inbound%'
      and trans_date >= '01-jan-2019' and trans_date < '01-jan-2020'
group by account, to_char(trans_date, 'mm-yyyy')
order by account;
```

EDIT: Per Comment, here is my SQL*PLUS session:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select account, to_char(trans_date, 'mm-yyyy') mnth_yr,
  2         (sum(total_duration)/60) as mou
  3  from chuck.cdr_data_summary@chuckdb
  4  where rate_band_type = 'ALC1' and account = '0204927766' and description_text like '%Inbound%'
  5        and trans_date >= '01-jan-2019' and trans_date < '01-jan-2020'
  6  group by account, to_char(trans_date, 'mm-yyyy')
  7  order by account;
select account, to_char(trans_date, 'mm-yyyy') mnth_yr,
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
ORA-02063: preceding line from CHUCKDB


SQL>
```

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the fact that you are querying a remote table.  Is the remote DB also Oracle?

Comment: It is also Oracle.

Comment: You might try copying your remote table to your local database, or at least some rows of it, and seeing if the error still happens.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with it.

- Lines #1 - 8 represent sample data
- Lines #9 onward are your query, slightly modified:

  - I used CTE as a source in line #12
  - lines #16 and 17 use dates, not strings (as you did, and you shouldn't)

---

```
SQL> with cdr_data_summary as
  2    (select '0204927766' account,
  3            120 total_duration,
  4            'ALC1' rate_band_type,
  5            'xxxInboundyyy' description_text ,
  6            date '2019-01-01' trans_date
  7     from dual
  8    )
  9  SELECT account,
 10         TO_CHAR(trans_date,'mm-yyyy')AS yr_mnth,
 11         SUM(total_duration)/ 60 AS mou
 12  from cdr_data_summary   -- chuck.cdr_data_summary@chuckdb
 13  WHERE rate_band_type = 'ALC1'
 14    AND account = '0204927766'
 15    AND description_text LIKE '%Inbound%'
 16    AND trans_date >= date '2019-01-01' --'01-jan-2019'
 17    AND trans_date < date '2020-01-01'  --'01-jan-2020'
 18  GROUP BY account,
 19           TO_CHAR(trans_date, 'mm-yyyy');

ACCOUNT    YR_MNTH        MOU
---------- ------- ----------
0204927766 01-2019          2

SQL>
```

Please, post your SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you really did and how Oracle responded.

Comment: Interesting - this runs in my environment.  I'm in SQL DEVELOPER - not sure what a SQL*Plus session is.

Comment: SQL*PLUS session copied to OP

Comment: Interesting. Try to run query I posted, with the CTE. *Maybe* it is about the database link?

Comment: Your CTE ran in my SQL DEVELOPER gui, and also now runs in SQL*PLUS session.  Things like this are why I prefer SQL SERVER.  The original query appears to be standard (ISO) SQL.  In any case... the issue isn't blocking anyone...